# Include в javascript

Tags: include, модульность, javascript

Как сделать инклюд (include) в javascript или как организовать идею модульности кода?

Причем возможность работы с nodejs -- нет.

Я попробовал сделать, как в этой статье:
http://www.artlebedev.ru/tools/technogrette/js/include/

Код, который я использую в качестве библиотеки, которая должна реализовывать инклюд:
http://img.artlebedev.ru/tools/technogrette/js/include/js_als.js

Но я скорее дизайнер, нежели программист, и чего-то не догоняю.

В html  я разместил код типа:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/js.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
```

Первый скрипт - это библиотека из статьи по ссылке выше.
Второй типа мой код, вот примерно что в нем есть:

```
js.include('scene');
//собственно это и есть весь файл.
```

И есть еще файл, который "модуль", в нем такой код:

```
js.module("createScene")
consloe.log("hi!wwwww");
js.module = function(path) {
    js.loadedModules[path] = true;

    var scene = document.createElement("div");
    scene.id = "scene";
    bod.appendChild(scene);
    consloe.log("hi!");

}

/*function createScene(){
    var scene = document.createElement("div");
    scene.id = "scene";
    bod.appendChild(scene);
}*/
```

Все в этом файле, соответственно, не работает, потому как в main ругается на инклюд.
Закомментированный блок илюстрирует идею. Типа есть функция, она что-то делает, но я эту функцию хочу разместить в отдельном файле.

Структура папок:

```
index.html -- в корне.  в нем подключаю
```

Все остальные файлы js расположены в папке js:

```
js/js.js
js/main.js
js/scene.js
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как либо запустить этот метод из статьи, либо реализовать принцип модульности как-то иначе, не прибегая к nodejs или подключая все через <script>?

Comment: [requirejs](http://stepansuvorov.com/blog/2012/10/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9-requirejs/)

Comment: и nodejs не нужен?

Comment: @Etki оформите как нибудь ответ. я вам плюс поставлю.
--это то, что мне нужно!

Comment: Можно глянуть здесь [OU.js](http://openingup.ru/development/OU-js/using) - простенький скрипт для инклюда с соблюдением зависимостей

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ из комментариев:

Для организации модулей js предполагается использовать использовать загрузчик requireJS.
[Вводная статья](http://stepansuvorov.com/blog/2012/10/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9-requirejs/)

Comment: А какие преимущества перед тем, чтобы просто создать `<script>` и назначить ему атрибут `src`?